# Python ValueError : ColumnTransformer, Column Ordering is Not Equal

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

I put together the following function that read csv, train the model and predict the request data.

I've got the following ValueError : Column ordering must be equal for fit and for transform when using the remainder keyword

The training data and the data used for prediction has exact the same number of column , e.g., 15. I am not sure how the "ordering" of the column could have changed.

```
~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in predict(self, X, **predict_params)
    417         Xt = X
    418         for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
--> 419             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    420         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt, **predict_params)
    421 

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in transform(self, X)
    581             if (n_cols_transform >= n_cols_fit and
    582                     any(X.columns[:n_cols_fit] != self._df_columns)):
--> 583                 raise ValueError('Column ordering must be equal for fit '
    584                                  'and for transform when using the '
    585                                  'remainder keyword')

ValueError: Column ordering must be equal for fit and for transform when using the remainder keyword
```

Function:

```
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[

    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])

#Putting data transformation and the model in a pipeline
rf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                     ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier(
                                        n_estimators=500,
                                        criterion="gini",
                                        max_features="sqrt",
                                        min_samples_leaf=4))])

rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

request_data = {'A': [request.A],
                'B': [request.B],
                'C': [request.C],
                'D': [request.D],
                'E': [request.E],
                'F': [request.F],
                'G': [request.G],
                'H': [request.H],
                'I': [request.I],
                'J': [request.J],
                'K': [request.K],
                'L': [request.L],
                'M': [request.M],
                'N': [request.N],
                'O': [request.O]}

df_resp = pd.DataFrame(data=request_data)
response = rf.predict(df_resp)

output = {"Safety Rating": response[0]}

return output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand from the error message is that `X_train.columns` and `df_resp.columns` are not the same but `.predict()` needs them to be.

In order to force this equality you could pass the column list of `X_train` as an argument when creating the dataframe:

`pd.DataFrame(data=request_data, columns=X_train.columns)`

Comment: But, when I predict(X_test), it works perfectly. It throw errors when I put them in a function and predict from class(request) which feed the request_data.

Comment: I can't see your variables `X_train` and `X_test`. Can you `assert X_train.columns == df_resp.columns`?

Comment: The df_resp is served for the user to put in the value from request data. This function is use for APIs. so X_train and X_test doesn't come into the picture. But before putting this function, I tried them in Notebook format, and it works.

Comment: What's the output for `X_train.columns`? Might be an index thing.

Comment: Index(['A', 'B', 'C',
       'D', 'E', 'F', 'G',
       'H', 'I', 'J',
       'K', 'L', 'M',
       'N', 'O'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: and output of df_resp is a dataframe. If I take out the dataframe, it throws the error of Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array={'A': ['Apple'], 'B': ['Two'],

Comment: `df_resp = pd.DataFrame(request_data, columns=X_train.columns)` could help to force the column equality. Your code looks sound for the rest...

Comment: LOVELY! Thank you so much. It works now. {'Safety Rating': 'L2'}

Comment: If you want to update your answer, I can check them off. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210848/discussion-between-cassie-l-and-jorijnsmit).

Comment: Hi @Jorijnsmit, I have the same error on the other function. Due to the function above used for API purposes and it took about 4 minutes to get response, can you please help me? Thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010040/python-function-valueerror-that-expecting-value-is-not-equal-to-trained-value

Answer (score 1):

You can use following generic function in order to sort columns correctly :

```
def rearrange_columns(df, first_order="categorical"):
    """
    ColumnTransformer of scikit-learn Pipeline changes the order of the dataframe columns.
    Use this function to reorder the features columns to be consistent with the ouptut of the pipeline
    """
    cat_ix = [ii for ii, col in enumerate(df.columns.values) if df[col].dtypes=="object"]
    num_ix = [ii for ii, col in enumerate(df.columns.values) if ii not in cat_ix]    
    new_order =  cat_ix + num_ix if first_order == "categorical" else num_ix + cat_ix    
    return [df.columns.values[ii] for ii in new_order]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I got same while I was working with sklearn ColumnTransformer. The Error behind this scene is at training time(during fit()) columntransformer pick the order of column by itelf and fit the prameters_ of transformers and when it's time for inference at that time eventhough we give a right shape of data and correct columns but still it will throw an error at columntransformer because **order matters here**.

Solution : It can be solved by loading a columntransformer and use one of it's attribute like **columntransformer._df_columns** and pass it to dataframe's column attribute so at the error it will yield an right order of attributes which column transformer is seeking for. That's how i get out of this error. One take reference of below example.

```
usecols = preprocessing_pipeline._df_columns.tolist()

if os.path.splitext(dataset_path)[-1] == '.csv':
     df = pd.read_csv(dataset_path,usecols = usecols)
else:
     df = pd.read_excel(dataset_path,usecols = usecols)
```

Hope this solution will help.