# sklearn pipeline transform ValueError that Expected Value is not equal to Trained Value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

Can you please help me to with the following function where I got the error of ValueError: Column ordering must be equal for fit and for transform when using the remainder keyword

(The function is called on a pickled sklearn pipeline that I had saved in GCP Storage.)

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-192-c6a8bc0ab221> in <module>
----> 1 safety_project_lite(request)

<ipython-input-190-24c565131f14> in safety_project_lite(request)
     31 
     32     df_resp = pd.DataFrame(data=request_data)
---> 33     response = loaded_model.predict(df_resp)
     34 
     35     output = {"Safety Rating": response[0]}

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    114 
    115         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 116         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    117         # update the docstring of the returned function
    118         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in predict(self, X, **predict_params)
    417         Xt = X
    418         for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
--> 419             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    420         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt, **predict_params)
    421 

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in transform(self, X)
    581             if (n_cols_transform >= n_cols_fit and
    582                     any(X.columns[:n_cols_fit] != self._df_columns)):
--> 583                 raise ValueError('Column ordering must be equal for fit '
    584                                  'and for transform when using the '
    585                                  'remainder keyword')

ValueError: Column ordering must be equal for fit and for transform when using the remainder keyword
```

Code:

```
def safety_project_lite_beta(request):
   client = storage.Client(request.GCP_Project)
   bucket = client.get_bucket(request.GCP_Bucket)
   blob = bucket.blob(request.GCP_Path)
   model_file = BytesIO()
   blob.download_to_file(model_file)
   loaded_model = pickle.loads(model_file.getvalue())

   request_data = {'A': [request.A],
   'B': [request.B],
   'C': [request.C],
   'D': [request.D],
   'E': [request.E],
   'F': [request.F]}

   df_resp = pd.DataFrame(data=request_data)
   response = loaded_model.predict(df_resp)

   output = {"Rating": response[0]}

   return output
```

Comment: What did you use to train the model with? Is it a dataframe as well? Can you `X_train.describe()`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I am able to get away with df_resp = pd.DataFrame(data=request_data, columns = 'A','B','C'...), just wonder if there is better way to mitigate the issue. X_train.describe() gives me the dataframe. And in terms of what I use to train the model, is the same as the before link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61001934/python-valueerror-columntransformer-column-ordering-is-not-equal/61002281?noredirect=1#comment107924490_61002281, but instead of do all the training in the function, I call .pkl from GCP that I saved from the trained model.

Comment: Please make your title less broad than "Python function". In this case the specific package is `sklearn`, the object is `Pipeline` and the specific method is `transform()`. And the error didn't have anything to do with pickling to/from GCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model can only predict if the data you feed it is of the same structure as it has been trained on.

To force the fact that `df_resp` has the same columns as `X_train`, pass a list of its columns along when building the dataframe:

```py
df_resp = pd.DataFrame(request_data, columns=X_train.columns)
```

If that variable is for some reason not available, you could pickle its column list (`X_train.columns`) and use it later:

```py
loaded_cols = pickle.loads([...])
df_resp = pd.DataFrame(data=request_data, columns=loaded_cols)
```

This ensures a more dynamic workflow where you could add columns more easily for example.

Comment: Thanks for the above explanation!